# How to determine which class is instantiated and access it through a variable in Java

Tags: java

I have an Interface `IGeneralEvents` and I have implemented three classes based on it `Social`, `Sport` and `Traditional`. All three of them are using singletons to make sure they are only instantiated once.

The three classes have some additional methods in them which are unique for each one.

I have also created a class to manage these events named `EventManager`. Depending on the date and time one of these three events will occur through the `EventManager`. The `EventManager` will instantiate one of them like below:

```
public class EventManager {
    
    public EventManager() {
        if (time_is_right()) {
            Social social_event = Social.getInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

In another class I need to know which is the current running event. So my approach of a solution was to do the following:

```
public class EventManager {
    public static IGeneralEvents current_event_instance = null;
    
    public EventManager() {
        if (time_is_right()) {
            Social social_event = new Social.getInstance();
            current_event_instance = social_event;
        }
    }
}
```

I created a static variable in the `EventManager` of type `IGeneralEvents` and tried to pass the instance of the event when it was decided in the constructor. When I do that and I call the `current_event_instance` with a method that does not exist in `IGeneralEvents` (e.g `current_event_instance.chat()`) then I obviously get `java: cannot find symbol` as the method is not available in the Interface.

What is the proper way to follow in order to be able to call something like `current_event_instance.chat()` from other classes ?

Comment: Please add a complete example to your question which illustrates the problem, including whatever compiler error messages you get.

Comment: It's hard for me to really tell what's going on, but it sounds like you may be working with the wrong abstractions. Users of an interface [should not care what class implements that interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860). If a method exists in one class but not another, then it _usually_ shouldn't be part of the interface (there are exceptions).

Comment: I'm with @yshavit, and your question smells of possibly being an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type question. Why do you need to know the type of the reference made to the interface variable? I have to wonder if there is a better overall approach to this problem. Consider using real-world types and code.

Comment: Whatever your desired behaviour is when you try to call a method from the wrong class - you could write it as a `default` method in the interface.  It's not clear whether that meets your requirement or not.  Your requirement sounds a little unusual to me.

Comment: @yshavit I have updated the content to reflect my problem in more detail.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you for this XY Problem, was not aware of it and yes i fell into it. I have updated the content of the question which hopefully now reflects my problem with more precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `instanceof` which checks if any given reference is an instance of the stated class, and there's the cast operator which does many completely unrelated things - one of them is to treat a given object as some more specific type - if it is of that type, then you can treat it as that type. If it is not, you get a ClassCastException. Combining them:

```
if (currentInstance instanceof A) {
  A a = (A) currentInstance;
  a.methodThatIsOnlyInA();
}
```

There's also the `.getClass()` method that all classes have; but note that if there's also, say, `class AChild extends A{}`, then:

```
Iab a = new AChild();
System.out.println(a instanceof A); // Prints true
System.out.println(a.getClass() == A.class); // Prints false
System.out.println(a instanceof AChild); // Prints true
System.out.println(a.getClass() == AChild.class); // Prints true
```

Comment: Indeed using the `instanceof` could be a solution but that would mean every time I need to check in different classes about the current instance I would need to do that check. And since there are three different types of classes I would need three different checks every time.

Comment: Yes, of course. If your method requires calling the `thisIsOnlyInA()` method, then it should accept an `A`, not an Iab.